# typescript : Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export class ServiceAreaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  _clickedPoint = [];

  this.serviceArea.getToken().subscribe((d) => {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.getServiceArea(this._clickedPoint);
  })
}

getServiceArea(pointArray: [], driveTimeList ? : any) {}
```

I've declared one class property called  `_clickedPoint = []` as an array. And the typescript takes it as `Array<any>`. 
At same time I've created a method inside the class to accept clicked point and i declared a method parameter called `pointArray:[]` same as like  `_clickedPoint`. Bu this time typescript takes this array without any type assigned . I just wanted to know why typescript is not assigning type `any` to method parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_clickedPoint = [];` is an initialization (with an empty array), of a member without a type. Typescript will infer the type of `_clickedPoint` to be an array, of type any (so `any[]`, or `never[]` depending on compiler settings, but you seem to be in the former case)

`pointArray: []` is a parameter of type empty tulpe (`[]`). Tuples at runtime are arrays but typescript will check that the length of the tuple and the items in the tuple are of the correct type (read more about tuples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple))

Typescript will infer types if none are specified, such as when you don't specify the type of the member, but will take the exact type you spelled out in a type annotation without adding anything to it, such as when you specified it for the parameter. In this case it is a bit confusing since the empty array literal `[]` has a different type than the empty tuple type (also `[]` but used as a type annotation)

What you really want is for `pointArray` to be an array type:

```
export class ServiceAreaComponent {
  _clickedPoint = [];
  test() {
    this.getServiceArea(this._clickedPoint);
  }
  getServiceArea(pointArray: any[], driveTimeList?: any) {
  }
}
```